# Group dataset to one row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this databaset

```
date        val1   val2    val3   val4
29/07/20    null   12.11   null   null
29/07/20    22.91  null    null   null      
29/07/20    null   null    15.18  null
29/07/20    null   null    null   85.72
```

how can I transform previous dataset to this one

```
date       val1    val2    val3    val4
29/07/20   22.91   12.11   15.18   85.72
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you get this dataset? Isn't it a result of pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select date, max(val1), max(val2), max(val3), max(val4)
from t
group by date;
```

In my experience, no one stores real tables in such a format.  Such tables are usually the result of aggregation queries that have an unnecessary key in the `group by`.  You might want to ask a new question about fixing the query that generates the data.